# HOW TO USE in Linux, IdentityServer4 with LetsEncript certificate for authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Please, could you tell me the way to configure the signing certificate for production?

In development the webapp works nice, I am using a self certificate in Windows.
But for production in Linux, I dont know how to use the certificate. Actually I am using LetsEncript, for the https, and as a CA, I suppose I can use their certificate for authentication with IdentityServer.

This is what I have right now.

IdentityServer Startup.cs file:

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment 
         environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });
 
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(
                options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnect")));    
            services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<Entities.User>, 
                PasswordHasher<Entities.User>>();
            services.AddScoped<ILocalUserService, LocalUserService>();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);
                 
            builder.AddProfileService<LocalUserProfileService>();

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore());
            }
             
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        }
     
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts(); 
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();  
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
        

        public X509Certificate2 LoadCertificateFromStore()
        {  
            string thumbPrint = "73ppppp1958888886d772222270000dbddb1aa37";
            using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, 
               StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certCollection = 
                    store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                    thumbPrint, true);
                if (certCollection.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The specified certificate wasn't found.");
                }
                return certCollection[0];
            }
        }
```

Appsetting.Json file:
It do not have nothing special about, just the connection string for identityserver.

Config.cs file:

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public static class Config
    { 
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids => new IdentityResource[]
        { 
           ...Irrelevant Code
        }
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis => new ApiResource[] 
        {  
          ...Irrelevant Code
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[] 
            {
                new Client
                {
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600, 
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,  
                    ClientName = "WebApp",
                    ClientId = "webapp",

                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,  
                    RequirePkce = true, 
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                         // Shoud I use here a domain for production like https://www.example.com:44300/signin-oidc ?
                        "https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                         // Shoud I use here a domain for production like https://www.example.com:44300/signout-callback-oidc ?
                        "https://localhost:44300/signout-callback-oidc"
                    },
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,      
                        "subscriptionlevel"
                    },
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("fakesecret".Sha256())
                    }
                } };
```

Comment: Let's encrypt is just used for the HTTPS part, not token signing. So is your question about configuring HTTPS with Lets encrypt or adding token-signing keys in production?

Comment: Hi Mr Nestenius. I do not know why I  thought I could use Lets Encrypt's certificate to signing. I guess my question  is more related to token.signing keys in production. I will try other routes now. Thanks again Mr Nestenius.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can use the same private key for both signing and HTTPS but I recommend you keep them separate for simplicity. Just so you can for example rotate keys (change keys) independently. Both token-singing and HTTPS depends on private/public keys so there's a lot of concepts in common.